# Android Studio Kotlin: ArrayAdapter won't let me override the getView function

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, overriding, android-arrayadapter

When trying to build my own getView function as they did in the tutorial I followed I get this error:

"Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getView(ILandroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;)Landroid/view/View;):"

```
class MyArrayAdapter(
    context: Context?,
    resourceId: Int,
    items: List<Cards?>?
) : ArrayAdapter<Cards?>(context!!, resourceId, items!!) {

    fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you did forgot the override modifier

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {}
```

Comment: Also "convertView" became a View? rather than a View